# How to write the file content faster using ServletOutputStream

Tags: jakarta-ee, servlets

We tried following ways in server side,

It takes to write around 55 Secs for 2.5 MB file content from MS-Amazon server to Java Client Code, Android Client code and IOS client code

Server Sample code 1

```
servletOutputStream = response.getOutputStream();
servletOutputStream.write(fileData);
servletOutputStream.flush();
servletOutputStream.close();
```

Server Sample code 2

```
BufferedOutputStream bufferedOutputStream = new                  BufferedOutputStream(servletOutputStream);
bufferedOutputStream.write(fileData);
bufferedOutputStream.flush();
bufferedOutputStream.close();`
```

Client side reader code

```
inputStream = httpConnection.getInputStream();
....
int nRead;
byte[] data = new byte[1024];
while ((nRead = inputStream.read(data, 0, data.length)) != -1) {
  buffer.write(data, 0, nRead);
}
buffer.flush();
buffer.close();
```

Please share  your ideas to improve download speed

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Adding the `BufferedOutputStream` won't make any difference. By default a servlet output stream is actually a `ByteArrayOutputStream` because the servlet container has to see the entire response before it writes any headers, so it can write a Content-Length header. This adds latency, but not 5 seconds worth. You can get around whatever latency it does add by using fixed-length or chunked response encoding. See the Servlet API for details. However I think you have a larger problem that you need to solve first, possibly a network or DNS or clock skew problem.